# Tankless Water Heater with Natural Gas Line possibly too small?

Tags: water-heater

Inspector thinks flex appliance gas line being only a 1/2" line approx 30" in length may not be sufficiently allowing enough gas to flow for the amount of BTUs the tankless water heater can
demand.

This specific tankless water heater can do 160,000 BTU/H
Model: RUCS75i → REU-KCM2528FFU-US

EDIT: Added a chart table from manufacture's guide for further clarification. [image]

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a reducer on the line so going up a size should be easy.  Those tankless heaters do take a lot.  Surprise the inspector is only thinking/guessing it is not big enough, they should have charts showing exactly what is needed for the BTUs.

Comment: What does the manufacturer's technical literature say? If they put a 1/2" port on their equipment and provided a 1/2" hose, then it's probably fine. To minimize the phone calls after each inspector expresses this same reservation, I expect that a manufacturer would specifically name the 1/2" hose as sufficient in its documentation.

Comment: @popham I uploaded a screenshot of gas pipe sizing and approach from the manufacturer's guide. Not too sure how to read it, maybe that further clarifies for you?

Comment: The heater comes with a 3/4" connection. That the table they include for Natural Gas (as opposed to Propane) does *not* include 1/2" connection is another indication that 1/2" is not such a great idea. Based on some rough calculations (since this is far out of my usual domain) including looking at charts from other places, it looks like 1/2" would be *marginal*. Given all of that, and the easy access and short distance, upgrading to 3/4" would make a *lot* of sense.

Comment: Are you supplying natural gas or propane? Who did the hookup, you or a licensed plumber? Why does there not appear to be a gas shut-off valve?

Comment: In our house one 3/4" line splits into two 1/2" lines to supply both a 120 kBTU/h Bosch Aquastar NG tankless and a 100 kBTU/h NG furnace.  Neither one shows signs of low gas flow. Your short length of 1/2" will be no problem if your gas pressure is OK. Ours is supposedly 0.25 psig or about 7" WC. You should have a shutoff valve on the solid gas pipe before the flex line. When you have the valve installed they could change to 3/4" all the way. I do not think you need it, but if your gas pressure would drop maybe you would. also later someone might want a 199 kBTU/h tankless.

Comment: You would probably not see any change in performance by changing to a 3/4" flex line. But if you want to measure performance before you change you could set output temp high (say 140 F) and measure flow rate at an unrestricted faucet like a tub spout or a laundry room hot faucet on full open.

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed the spec sheet for your unit and based on that information, 1/2" gas line is okay.  Though a shut off valve needs to be located in the same room as the appliance the line serves, so that should be addressed.  Also, I guess it's a "no no" to use teflon tape on the flex connection as it relies on pressure against the tapered fitting.  (based on what I've read)

[image: spec sheet]

Comment: I saw that too. So far I'm getting kind of mixed messages. On another plumbers forum the response I received was that it was undersized. The spec sheet says 1/2 compatible. The Owner's guide (attached in the OP) doesn't include 1/2 pipe size in the table.

Comment: Personally, I'd go by whatever size the inlet is.  Where the flex line attaches, is there an adaptor on the bottom of the unit that increases the 1/2" to something larger?  For the cost and time it would take to switch out the 1/2" flex to 3/4" to make everyone happy, I'd just do it and be done with it.  I ran 3/4" to a Mr. Heater even though it steps down at the unit.

Comment: With no gas appliance knowledge, but while wearing my "marketing-speak decoder ring", I would read "½ in. compatible" as meaning no more than that it is safe to use, and will "work" (but not necessarily at full capacity).